# In Django how to add a placeholder to a form based on model charfield

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a form:

```py
class SideEffectForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = SideEffect
        fields = ['se_name']

    def __init__(self, *args, p, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if p == 'antipsychotic':

            self.fields['se_name'].choices = [
                ("insomnia_and_agitation", "Insomnida and Agitation"),
                ("akathisia", "Akathisia"),
                ("dystonia", "Dystonia"),
            ]
```

That is based on this model:

```py
class SideEffect(TimeStampedModel):

    SE_CHOICES = [
        ("insomnia_and_agitation", "Insomnida and Agitation"),
        ("akathisia", "Akathisia"),
        ("anticholinergic_effects", "Anticholinergic Side Effects")
    ]

    se_name = models.CharField("",max_length=200, choices=SE_CHOICES, blank=False)

    concern = models.IntegerField("",default=50)

    case = models.ForeignKey(Case, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And this is the view:

```py
class CaseView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    model = Case
    template_name = "se_balance/se_balance.html"
    
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        p = self.request.GET.get("p", None)
        sideeffect_formset = SideeffectFormSet(queryset=SideEffect.objects.none(),
                                                form_kwargs={'p': p})


        return self.render_to_response(
            { "page_title": p.capitalize(),
              "sideeffect_formset": sideeffect_formset,
              "sideeffect_formsethelper": SideEffectFormSetSetHelper,
            }
        )

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        p = self.request.GET.get("p", None)

        case_instance = Case(pharm_class_name=p)
        sideeffect_formset = SideeffectFormSet(data=self.request.POST, form_kwargs={'p': p})
        case_instance.save()

        if sideeffect_formset.is_valid():
            print('seform valid')
            sideeffect_name = sideeffect_formset.save(commit=False)
            for sideeffect in sideeffect_name:
                sideeffect.case = case_instance
                sideeffect.save()

            return redirect(
                reverse(
                    "results",
                    kwargs = {"case_id": case_instance.case_id}                )
            )
```

As it stands the form displays the first option. I would however like to have a place holder e.g. 'Please select a side effect'. I could do this by having it as one of the options (e.g.  `(None, 'This is the placeholder prompt')`) but would prefer not to as then would need to implement measures to stop the placeholder being saved as a valid user entry. I have tried a range of suggestions on the site but none have been suitable.

Comment: Do you want a placeholder or something like empy_label? Can you please clarify? And also share the view.

Comment: @SunderamDubey I have edited, I want something that says 'select an option', but I don't want the form to be able to be submitted if that placeholder has not been deslected and an option selected form the dropdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You stated:

> I could do this by having it as one of the options (e.g.  (None, 'This is the placeholder prompt')) **but would prefer not to as then would need to implement measures to stop the placeholder being saved as a valid user entry.**

No, that's not true, when we set  `(None, 'This is the placeholder prompt')` there's no need to write the custom logic for not saving selected option in the database as valid user entry.

An Excerpt from the [`Django-doc`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices) about this issue.

> Unless blank=False is set on the field along with a default then a label containing "---------" will be rendered with the select box. **To override this behavior, add a tuple to choices containing None; e.g. (None, 'Your String For Display'). *Alternatively, you can use an empty string instead of None where this makes sense - such as on a CharField.***

## Solution:

You can simply do this `(None, 'please select the side effect')`, but as stated while using `CharField` you should use `('', 'please select the side effect')` this instead and also you've already set `blank=False`.

Try this:

```py
class SideEffectForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = SideEffect
        fields = ['se_name']

    def __init__(self, *args, p, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if p == 'antipsychotic':

            self.fields['se_name'].choices = [
                ('','Please select a side effect'),
                ("insomnia_and_agitation", "Insomnida and Agitation"),
                ("akathisia", "Akathisia"),
                ("dystonia", "Dystonia"),
            ]
```

After, doing this, see source code through `Ctrl+U` and you'll see below code of html:

```html
<select ...> 
    <option value="" selected>please select the side effect</option>

    <option value="insomnia_and_agitation">Insomnida and Agitation</option>

    <option value="akathisia">Akathisia</option>

    <option value="dystonia">Dystonia</option>

</select>
```

And `selected` value doesn't save in database, so if you submit form with it, you'll see the error of required.

Comment: Thank you - but is there a way that rather than going to an error page - the page just e.g. reloads or highlights the box to emphasise a selection must be made?

Comment: @RobMcC But with choices, we are bound to use these two, as choices default widget is `Select` and there is not option to set things like empty_label unlike in `ModelChoiceField` which is made through `ForeignKey`.

Comment: Thanks @SunderamDubey I will accept. PS if anyone has the same issue the answer is that you just need to amend the Post part of your view to have an else statement for is the form is not valid to  to basically just return whatever the Get part of the view is

Comment: @RobMcC Anyway, If you want, make edit to my answer according to your need, which will help to future readers, and I'll approve it.