# How to modify my ORM to show the date in the select?

Tags: python, django

I would appreciate your help friends since I am new and there are several things that I do not master!

I have a data record and a date is saved in each of the records, then I need to display the information depending on the date it was saved, when viewing the date data in my select it is displayed as follows

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Klg5B.jpg)

This is the code of my `forms` where I create the `select`, I imagine that the answer to my problem is to modify the ORM (which I have tried in several ways and I can't do it) and the data must be `distinct` so that the month does not repeat

```
class Report2Form(Form):
    reportDate = ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=ConsElect.objects.values_list('date', flat=True), 
        widget=Select(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            # ('F , Y') This is how it appears to me as 'April, 2023'
        }),
    )
```

This is my model

```
class ConsElect(models.Model):
    pgd = models.ForeignKey(TipoPGD, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='conselect')
    date= models.DateField(default=datetime.now)  
    read_morning = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    read_day = mod
```

I need help so that my select is as I need!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for the [.dates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#dates) method using the "month" as the 'kind' argument. The "month" kind will, per the linked documentation, **"returns a list of all distinct year/month values for the field."** See the documentation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#dates for more examples and options.

The filter would then become something like:

```
queryset=ConsElect.objects.dates("date", "month")
```

I believe in your case though, you want to use a ChoiceField instead of a ModelChoiceField. The selection is not bound to a specific record, but a calculated list of month and year combinations. **Note the ChoiceField uses 'choices' instead of queryset.** Putting the filter in the `__init__` method will get a current list of the dates. If you do it in the field definition, records entered after you last restarted the service will not be included as they'll be calculated as at the time you started the service.

Try something like:

```
class Report2Form(Form):

    report_date = ChoiceField(
        choices=[],
        widget=Select(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            # ('F , Y') This is how it appears to me as 'April, 2023'
        }),
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['report_date'].choices = [(f"{d:%Y-%m}", f"{d:%B, %Y}") for d in ConsElect.objects.dates("date", "month")]
```

In your `views.py`, you'd call this like:

```
form = Report2Form()
```

I haven't tested the code above, and have been typing it directly in here, so it may be slightly off. I suggest changing it to a choice field, as it isn't really pointing or bound to a record in `ConsElect`. Instead it is a list of choices evaluated at time of form instantiation so newly entered dates will be included in the choices. The choices end up being a list of tuples of something like [("2023-03", "March, 2023"), ]. This will put the first element of the tuple in the select's value, with the second element as the display text visible to the user.

Comment: Ok my friend I understand what you want to do, but it gives me the following error: TypeError: ModelChoiceField.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'queryset'

Comment: I appreciate her help and I ask for a little patience to understand since I am really new to django

Comment: Change it to ChoiceField, not ModelChoiceField

Comment: ok I already changed it, but now it gives the following error:.TypeError: Field.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queryset'.
 what is "month" for?

Comment: How are you calling the form in your view?

Comment: please update your question and add your view in your question as well/

Comment: in my `view` `get_context_data`, I pass it in as part of a dictionary of the `'form' context: Report2Form(),`

Comment: you may need to edit your question, or ask a new one with more information about the error you are seeing (including line number) and which line that is in your code.

Comment: Hello friend, sorry for not having responded sooner, checking the code once more and correcting a piece of information that was incorrectly placed. I can tell you that it works perfectly, I appreciate her help and I apologize for not having had time to respond sooner

Comment: Friend, could you tell me how I can put an `initial value` that is: "Select an option".
Well, I have reviewed several options on the internet and none have worked.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72746017/4872140 for similar, or start a new question.

Comment: Hello @AMG I checked the article you suggested, but still I can't create what I need. I created a new question on the subject and ask if you have time to review it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76158607/i-cant-add-a-1st-empty-option-in-my-select