# I can't add a 1st empty option in my select

Tags: python, django

I have the following form

```
class Report3Form(Form):  
    fecha = ChoiceField(    
        choices = [],          
        widget=Select(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
        }),
    )
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['fecha'].choices = [(f"{d:%Y-%m}", f"{d:%B, %Y}") for d in ConsumoElect.objects.dates("fecha", "month")]
```

That is based on this model:

```
class ConsumoElect(models.Model):
    pgd = models.ForeignKey(TipoPGD, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='consumoelect')
    fecha = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    fecha_AM = models.CharField(max_length=20)  
    lec_madrugada = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    lec_dia = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    lec_pico = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    reactivo = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    dato = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    total = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

The form shows a select with the month and its year as if a distinct was used in the ORM, I need the first thing that the select shows to be an empty value that says "select a date".

This link shows an example of what I want, but I can't adapt it to my problem

[In Django how to add a placeholder to a form based on model charfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72714228/in-django-how-to-add-a-placeholder-to-a-form-based-on-model-charfield/72746017#72746017)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate a fixed 1-item list with the "select a date" and the calculated list

In this case, since you did not specify the "blank=True" parameter for the the field, the default will be blank=False and the user will be forced to select an item from the combo box.

```
self.fields['fecha'].choices = \
[('','Select a date')] + \
[(f"{d:%Y-%m}", f"{d:%B, %Y}") for d in ConsumoElect.objects.dates("fecha", "month")]
```